# Ionic 3, set device specific spash-screen image as background

Tags: ionic3

I am looking for a way to get hold of the device specific splashscreen, that would be used by the https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/splash-screen/ plugin, and set it as the background image on one of the pages.

It is possible to have a generic image, and use it as a background; but I am wondering if there is a way to get hold of the actual image used in splash screen.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think you can dinamically chage the splash-screen by you can change the device background image dynamically

Comment: I dont want to dynamically change splashscreen, rather reuse the appropriate splash screen image as a background image. How can I get the valid URL for accessing the spash screen image?